# Initialize a const map which has shared_ptr as values

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am trying to create a const map with key as int and second value is shared_ptr to a class.

Let say, I have a class A with B, and C derived from A.
I want to be able to create a map

```
const map<int, shared_ptr<A>> mymap
```

and initialize the map with the values:

```
{1, new B()} and {2, new C()}
```

But using initializer list gives error. 
Any help on how can I do this?

Comment: Please include the errors that you get, the compiler that you used and perhaps a complete small program that shows what you did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to construct a `shared_ptr` implicitly from a raw pointer. You have to initialize your map this way:

```
const map<int, shared_ptr<A>> mymap = {
    {1, shared_ptr<B>(new B())}, 
    {2, shared_ptr<C>(new C())}
    };
```

Paragraph 20.7.2.2 of the C++11 Standard demands `shared_ptr<>`'s constructor that accept a raw pointer to be `explicit`:

```
template<typename Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y* p);
```

The problem is that you are trying to construct instances of `std::pair<int, shared_ptr<A>>` by passing a raw pointer as the second argument to the `pair<>`'s constructor, which accepts a `shared_ptr<A>`. Basically, this is the same as:

```
pair<int, shared_ptr<A>> mymap(1, new B()); // ERROR!
pair<int, shared_ptr<A>> mymap(1, shared_ptr<B>(new B())); // OK
```

This said, unless you have very good reasons to do otherwise and you really know what you are doing, it is always better to use `std::make_shared<>()` to create shared pointers, both because of efficiency (it performs one memory allocation instead of two) and exception-safety (it won't leak if the constructor of `B` or `C` throws an exception). Thus, your map initialization should look like:

```
const map<int, shared_ptr<A>> mymap = {
    {1, make_shared<B>()}, 
    {2, make_shared<C>()}
    };
```

Comment: Probably better with std::make_shared.

Comment: @Shiroko: Indeed. I just wanted to show the nature of the problem. Will add this to my answer.